# Align dropdown select in CSS horizontally

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a form with 3 dropdown and 2 buttons. But I can't align the 3 dropdowns and 2 buttons horizontally. I tried to put margin-top and margin-left in each dropdown and buttons but when I viewed in other browser like Mozilla and Macbook Chrome, the html elements got messed up.

How to fix this?

Here's the full CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/mj9okkzd/5/

```
#sl_form {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    background: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 1em 0.75em 1.25em 0.75em;
}
```

Desired Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For each element (Dropdown's and buttons) you can set their top alignments and side alignments.

Example:

```
margin-left: Distance in px
margin-top: Distance in px
```

Comment: I tried that, but when I view it in Mozilla/Safari, the UI will messed up

Comment: If you look into making your page responsive it should stay in the same place relative to the browser's resolution

Comment: But that's not what happened. When I check it in Mac Chrome, the html elements getting messy. Same with Firefox